# React - download file button

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to use a button to download file stored in `public` folder. I have `test.xlsx` in `public` folder, and here is my code

```
<a href={"/test.xlsx"} download target='_blank'>
    <button> click </button>
</a>
```

However, when I go to the website, it says `Failed - No file`. How can I fix it? Do I have to edit `webpack.config.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this method, this should work. Using a file-saver hook.

```
import React from "react";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

export default function App() {
  const saveFile = () => {
    saveAs(
      "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
      "example.pdf"
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={saveFile}>download</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to know a native way instead of using a third-party dependency. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works 100% but you only need the download

`<a href="/test.xlsx" download ><button> click </button></a>`

I would suggest remove the target='_blank' as *every browser can respond differently* and may not trigger the download especially if it is counted as an attempt to redirect to a viral alternative like a popup advert etc.
[image]

What is wrong is checking the URL so if a browsers sees `/` it will attempt to open the download from its own root and logically I do not have your /test.xlsx in my c:\ folder. but it is in the working folder

[image]

However it is in the HTML working folder

[image]

so all I need to do is simply ensure I use the correct relative call to the valid files location e.g. this if its in the same folder

```
<body>
<a href="./test.xlsx" download ><button> click </button></a>
<body>
```

or simpler for current work folder if it is the `public` folder remove the path

```
<body>
<a href="test.xlsx" download ><button>Click to download test.xlsx</button></a>
<body>
```

[image]